# Solve an elementary function integration

Tags: integration

How to solve the following integral

${\int_\Theta ^{2x + 2\alpha \sqrt x } {\left[ {x - {{\left( {\frac{{y - 2x}}{{2\alpha }}} \right)}^2}} \right]} ^{ - \frac{1}{2}}}dy$,

where $2x-2\alpha \sqrt x<\Theta<2x + 2\alpha \sqrt x$, $x>0$, $\alpha$ is a real number.

Comment: You can do it by using the standard integral $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{k-u^2}}\, du = \sin^{-1}\left(u/\sqrt{k}\right)+C,$$ where $k$ is a positive constant. To make things clearer, you can firstly use the substitution $u = \frac{y-2x}{2\alpha}$ in your integral to get it into this form (and as usual remember to change the limits of integration and $dy$ appropriately).

Comment: Your integrand is essentially $1/\sqrt{c^2-y^2}$.

Comment: @Minus One-Twelfth, Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @Clayton, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_\Theta^{2x+2\alpha\sqrt{x}} \frac1{\sqrt{x-\left( \frac{y-2x}{2\alpha}\right)^2}}\mathrm{d}y=\left[2\alpha\arcsin{\left(\frac{y-2x}{2\alpha\sqrt{x}}\right)}\right]_\Theta^{2x+2\alpha\sqrt{x}}=\alpha\pi-2\alpha\arcsin{\left(\frac{\Theta-2x}{2\alpha\sqrt{x}}\right)}$$